# With MongoMapper, how can I find records where an ID doesn't exist in another table?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I have two models, User and Class. In MySQL, I could find users *not* in a class with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM Classes)
```

How can I do something similar with MongoMapper? I've been able to in the Mongo console with:

```
db.users.find({user_id:{$ne:db.classes.find({}, {user_id:1})}});
```

but I can't figure out the syntax using MongoMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongo snippet you posted is two queries.  The MongoMapper equivalent is:

```
classy_users_ids = MyClass.fields(:user_id).find_each.map(&:user_id).uniq
classless_users  = User.where(:id.nin => classy_users_ids)
```

If you have a lot of users, the first query might be more efficient if you skip the conversion to `MongoMapper::Document`'s with the following:

```
classy_users_ids = MyClass.collection.distinct(:user_id)
```

Comment: I like the .distinct code, I didn't know about that -- thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If they are related like `Class ... has_many :users` you can match directly against `user_ids`:

```
Class.where(:user_ids.ne => user.id)
```